# PHP variable overlaying image echoed inside table

Tags: php, html, calendar

I'm using PHP to output a timelined calendar-type display of 3-4 staff shift durations for each day of the week in the layout shown:

```
|=========|==========================================================|
|         |                 |       STEVE       |                    |
|         |==========================================================|
|  $DATE  |       |     SARAH      |                                 |
|         |==========================================================|
|         |                                  |       JODIE       |   |
|=========|==========================================================|
```

It worked correctly when using IMG SRC for everything but then I need to put the hyperlink text on it. I now seem to be losing the proper veritcal dimensions of the middle span, or it skips to the next row. I was trying to secure the span boundaries better with span styling as seen or through CSS but couldn't figure it out. Am I heading in the right direction ?

Also... With the different row height of the $date box compared to the shift rows, would it be better to be using more div/span instead of TD/TR to create the desired output ?

```
    <?php
require'connect.php';

$query="SELECT mname,
((((TIME_TO_SEC(start) / '60') / '15') * '10') - '400'),
((((TIME_TO_SEC(finish) / '60') / '15') * '10') - (((TIME_TO_SEC(start) / '60') / '15') * '10')),
('960' - (((TIME_TO_SEC(finish) / '60') / '15') * '10'))
FROM schedule WHERE date >= NOW() AND date <= NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY ORDER BY date asc";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
$a=0;

echo"<div><center><IMG SRC='images/filler1.jpg' WIDTH=80 HEIGHT=40></TD><IMG SRC='images/filler1.jpg' WIDTH=560 HEIGHT=40></center></div>";
echo"<div><center><TABLE WIDTH=640 BORDER=0 CELLPADDING=0 CELLSPACING=0>";

while ($a < $num){
$mname=mysql_result($result,$a,"mname");
$width1=mysql_result($result,$a,"((((TIME_TO_SEC(start) / '60') / '15') * '10') - '400')");
$width2=mysql_result($result,$a,"((((TIME_TO_SEC(finish) / '60') / '15') * '10') - (((TIME_TO_SEC(start) / '60') / '15') * '10'))");
$width3=mysql_result($result,$a,"('960' - (((TIME_TO_SEC(finish) / '60') / '15') * '10'))");
$rowheight=("120" / $num);

if ($a < 1){echo"
<TR>
<TD><IMG SRC='images/Shift_06.jpg' WIDTH=80 HEIGHT=120></TD>
<TD>
<IMG SRC='images/filler1.jpg' width='$width1' height='$rowheight'>
<span style='display:inline-block; width:$width2; height:$rowheight; text-align:center; font-family: Annifont; font-size: 13px; background-color:#b0c4de; border:none;'><a href='$name.html'>$mname</a></span>
<IMG SRC='images/filler1.jpg' width='$width3' height='$rowheight'>";}

if ($a > 0){echo"<br>
<IMG SRC='images/filler1.jpg' width='$width1' height='$rwoheight'>
<span style='display:inline-block; width:$width2; height:$rowheight; text-align:center; font-family: Annifont; font-size: 13px; background-color:#b0c4de; border:none;'><a href='$name.html'>$mname</a></span>
<IMG SRC='images/filler1.jpg' width='$width3' height='$rowheight'>";}
$a++;}

echo"</TD></TR></TABLE></center></div>";

if (!mysql_query($query))
  {die('Error: ' . mysql_error());}   

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: This seems more like an HTML/CSS problem, so it's better if you show some of your rendered HTML instead of the PHP. Furthermore, if you can make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing your exact problem, better.

Comment: I haven't made any HTML so far, just been working on this PHP output.

Answer (score 0):

I went back to using TR/TD rather than span.
Problem I had before was that each TD was a different width $variable for each staff shift duration from the database. This was not creating the correct time layouts.

Instead I created the required 56 timeline increments in TD columns above.
This then allowed me to use the width $variable for COLSPAN instead of TD width in pixels.

Hope this helps anybody else trying to output a similar calendar layout.

```
echo"<div><center><TABLE WIDTH=640 BORDER=0 CELLPADDING=0 CELLSPACING=0><TR>
<TD width='80' height='40' background='images/filler1.jpg'></TD>";
while ($b != "56"){echo"
<TD width='10' height='40' background='images/filler1.jpg'></TD>";
$b++;}
echo"</TR>";

        if ($a < "1"){echo"<TR><TD ROWSPAN=4><IMG SRC='images/Shift_06.jpg' WIDTH=80 HEIGHT=120></TD>
            <TD COLSPAN='$width1' height='$roheight' align='center' valign='middle' background='images/filler1.jpg'></TD>
            <TD COLSPAN='$width2' height='$roheight' align='center' valign='middle' background='images/filler2.jpg' class='ChillOutGrey2'>
            <a href='$mname.html'>$mname</a></TD>
            <TD COLSPAN='$width3' height='$roheight' align='center' valign='middle' background='images/filler1.jpg'></TD>
            </TR>";}
        if ($a > "0") {echo"<TR>
            <TD COLSPAN='$width1' height='$roheight' align='center' valign='middle' background='images/filler1.jpg'></TD>
            <TD COLSPAN='$width2' height='$roheight' align='center' valign='middle' background='images/filler2.jpg' class='ChillOutGrey2'>
            <a href='$mname.html'>$mname</a></TD>
            <TD COLSPAN='$width3' height='$roheight' align='center' valign='middle' background='images/filler1.jpg'></TD>
            </TR>";}
$a++;}
echo "</TABLE></center></div>";
```